# Github actions run only if above certain Python version

Tags: github-actions

How do I run a Github action task only for certain python versions?

I want to run a command for python >= 3.6, among a build matrix including
python 2.7, 3.5, 3.6, 3.9.1, and the latest python 3.

Here is the relevant excerpt showing my (not very elegant) approach:

```
jobs:
  run-tests:
    name: Run tests
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    defaults:
      run:
        shell: bash -l {0}
    strategy:
      matrix:
        python-version: [2.7, 3.5, 3.6, '3.9.1', 3]
      fail-fast: false
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - uses: conda-incubator/setup-miniconda@v2
        with:
          auto-update-conda: true
          python-version: ${{ matrix.python-version }}
      - name: Install testing dependencies (Python 3.6+)
        if: ${{ matrix.python-version >= 3.6 || matrix.python-version == '3.9.1'  || matrix.python-version == 3 }}
        run: |
          conda install -c anaconda -c conda-forge --file requirements-linting-old.txt libstdcxx-ng
```

The problem is that python-version in the matrix is a float by default, and while one can do `if ${{matrix.python-version >= 3.6 }}` , this does not work when testing patch versions (3.9.1), which need to be specified as a string, or when testing the latest python 3 (with just "3").

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know this was asked a while ago but I finally had this issue as well. I overcame it by splitting the major and minor versions into separate matrix.

```yaml
matrix:
  python-major-version: [3]
  python-minor-version: [8, 9, 10, 11]
```

Only thing to consider with this approach is if there is a major version change you might need to do exclusions.
I also added `python-version` to the `env` for the build, see below:

```yaml
env:
    python-version: ${{ format('{0}.{1}', matrix.python-major-version, matrix.python-minor-version) }}
```

This gives you the ability to provide `python-version` when you need the full version.

```yaml
- uses: actions/checkout@v3
- name: Set up Python ${{ env.python-version }}
  uses: actions/setup-python@v3
  with:
    python-version: ${{ env.python-version }}
```

but you can also refer to them separately to compare the minor version.

```yaml
- name: Analysing the code with pylint
  if: ${{ matrix.python-minor-version < 10 }}
```

Comment: Caution: if you specify a dynamic python version, such as "3.12-dev" or "*", then this method will NOT work at all.

Comment: True, for more "advanced" cases like that creating a custom github action would probably be more suited to have it parse the version into a comparable way or something else.

Comment: In fact I've found out it's possible to adapt your solution for this case, by using the [output python-version](https://github.com/actions/setup-python/blob/main/docs/advanced-usage.md#python-version) instead of input one: `steps.setuppy.outputs.python-version` given the setup-python action is given `id: setuppy`